# Exact Definition of simple bit pattern?

Tags: arithmetic, binary, bit-manipulation

I didn't find an exact description for this, but I know that any integer type is a simple bit pattern, it seems to me that the simple bit pattern should have a more exact description

as I understand simple bit pattern are synonym for [**`primitives`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type)

Comment: Without context, this question is meaningless, and I don't quite agree to say that "any integer type is a simple bit pattern". This is a simple bit pattern: $010101010101010101\cdots$.

Comment: Yves Daoust, I don't quite understand you,for example in what context would the question make sense?

Comment: Where did you meet the expression "simple bit pattern" ?

Comment: in Head First Java 3ed. “ Variables come in two flavors: primitive and object reference. Primitives hold fundamental values (think: simple bit patterns) including integers, booleans, and floating-point num- bers.”  I just wanted to know if there was any general definition

Comment: This is informal speech and IMO not so appropriate. I see no relevant general definition. The only basic types I could tell have a pattern are the floats/doubles.

Comment: thank you, that's what I thought too when I read it.